# best plotting library for iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

What is the best plotting library for the iPhone's iOS SDK? I tried out core plot but looks like it's still pretty unstable.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure about the type of app you have but..

You can

A) Waste your time with Core Plot, which as mediocre as it is for a framework, is the best option for a native solution.

B) Use one of the 19 billion excellent Javascript and/or HTML 5 charting frameworks out there and import them with a web view, then go to dinner.

Frankly, I always go with B when possible.

Answer (score 5):

I think your assessment of [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) was a bit premature. Well the API is "unstable" (there has not been a 1.0 release as of now, Sept. 2010), many applications (including my own) are using Core Plot in production on both iOS and OS X. I have not experienced any stability issues with Core Plot, nor have any of our crash reports from the field implicated Core Plot.

The Core Plot developers are very active on the Core Plot mailing list. If you've had specific issues, I would start there (or post targeted questions on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 4):

Core Plot seems to work OK, though I found it hard to understand with really poor examples (searching around finds lots of examples that are out of date with the API).

I think it's probably the Charlie Brown Christmas tree of frameworks, with a little API and documentation love, it could be great.

I didn't end up using it in the final version of the app I was making, but it was wholly for reasons not related to how Core Plot worked.

Comment: Careful, you badmouthed Core Plot. Their contribs will be here any second to take you away. (totally agree with everything you said, it's shabby. really shabby.)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree, Core Plot is sort of a mixed bag but it is the best option out there for now. My hope is that over time it will get better. It definitely is being actively developed. With that said, I am using it in my app with very few problems. It took some time to set up since their documentation is not the best, but once I figured it out (I actually had to read a lot of their code to understand what the problems were), I was able to make it work.