# Plotting apps for ios

Tags: ios, math, plot

I have seen some plotting apps for ios, such as Graph It and Quick Graph.  I am wondering what libraries they are using for creating plots and how to integrate those libraries into ios apps. Thanks a lot and happy new year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [best plotting library for iOS sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792128/best-plotting-library-for-ios-sdk)

Comment: Thanks Eric. I checked the thread before, where CORE PLOT was discussed. But I thought CORE PLOT is not good enough for serious scientific applications. Maybe I am wrong ....

Comment: That's a pretty old question. Core Plot has grown quite a bit since then and a lot of people have found it useful. You'll have to give a better description of your specific requirements for us to say if it would meet your needs or not. My vote to close your question was simply because this general question has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer for those specific apps, but I can think of some things for you to look at. One is gnuplot--the trouble here might be getting it into suitable form to use as a library rather than using it as a command-line tool, since AFAIK there is no NSTask or fork()-ing under iOS. Another would be to embed PERL; the only real hard part of plotting is evaluating the expression to be plotted, which is trivial in something like PERL. And of course there are other libraries dedicated to expression evaluation which may be more suitable, depending on exactly what you want to plot.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Actually I have written codes for expression evaluation using flex and bison. What I want is a library function that accepts an array of doubles and then give a 2D/3D plot.

Comment: OK. If you have the points to plot, I would definitely recommend gnuplot.

Comment: ["gnuplot with iOS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088657/gnuplot-with-ios/12014386#12014386) answer provides some insights for tweaking gnuplot source for use on iOS.